# Is there a way to set JMS to use SSL/TLS connecting to IBM MQ?

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, tls1.2

We have a Java application that uses JMS to communicate with IBM MQ. A part of their requirement is now to use TLS. Is there a way to do this? The parameters they were expecting to add are:

- sslCipherSuite
- hostname
- port
- channel

Is there any system environment property that we can set to JMS for this parameters?

the current code uses

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

and we use to a config file to set system env variables.

```
environment.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", this.config.get("JMS_JndiContextFactory"));
            this.setJndiExtraParameters(environment, this.config.get("JMS_JndiExtraParameters"));
            while (!this.state.atLeast(State.GOT_FACTORY) && iterator.hasNext()) {
                environment.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", this.urlUsed = iterator.next());
                try {
                    JmsClient.LOGGER.debug("Looking up connection factory");
                    this.factory = (ConnectionFactory)new InitialContext(environment).lookup(this.config.get("JMS_FactoryName"));
                    this.state = State.GOT_FACTORY;
                }
```

im thinking if there is a way to set only another set of system properties instead of using
MQConnectionFactory

so we don't have to change something in the code?

i posted a similar question , reposted it because of lack of clarity

Comment: You are supposed to edit the question that was closed rather than deleting it and opening a new question.  There is no recommended way to specify the TLS details with out a code change unless you already link your JNDI to a CCDT, in this case it would simple to update the CCDT to have the TLS details required.

Comment: @JoshMc Ill take note of this the next time I post another question. thanks for confirming btw